# Django: Error when trying to add a new app

Tags: django, django-apps, django-comments

I am trying to follow the steps here:

http://dev.svetlyak.ru/optional-email-in-django-comments-en/

to make the "Email Address" field in the Django comments app optional.  Specifically, I created a file called 'mycomments.py' with the following contents:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.comments.forms import CommentDetailsForm
from django.utils.translation import ungettext, ugettext_lazy as _

class CommentForm(CommentDetailsForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email address"), required=False)

def get_form():
    return CommentForm
```

And placed it in the root folder for my Django project (the same folder that contains manage.py and settings.py).  Then, I added 'mycomments' to the settings.py file as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'blogs',
    'mycomments',
)

COMMENTS_APP = 'mycomments'
```

But then when I do 'python manage.py runserver', I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x8bb208c>>
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 88, in inner_run
self.validate(display_num_errors=True)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
self._populate()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
self.load_app(app_name, True)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 83, in load_app
if not module_has_submodule(app_module, 'models'):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in module_has_submodule
for entry in package.__path__:  # No __path__, then not a package.

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'
```

And the dev server doesn't start up.  Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django app should be (at minimum) a directory with `__init__.py` and `models.py` files. So create `mycomments` dir, put your code in `__init__.py` and add empty `models.py` there.

Comment: Thank you!  This solved the issue.  So in the example given in the tutorial I linked to, did the author just create a dir called "firefly" and put his code into a file named "my_comments.py" inside that directory, and leave his __init__.py file blank?